# NAPW On One Line

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make this appear on one line on my site:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/LocalBusiness">
   <span itemprop="name">My Business Name</span>
   <div itemprop="address" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
     <span itemprop="streetAddress">My Road</span>
     <span itemprop="addressLocality">My Town</span>,
     <span itemprop="addressRegion">My City</span>
     <span itemprop="postalCode">My Postcode</span>
   </div>
   Phone: <span itemprop="telephone">My Telephone</span>
</div>
```

It currently shows as:

```
My Business Name

My Road, My Town, My City, My Postcode

My Telephone Number
```

and I'd like it to show as:

```
My Business Name, My Road, My Town, My City, My Postcode, My Telephone Number
```

Any ideas please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `display:inline-block;` to the `<div>`

**CSS**

```
div.yourclass{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/luispa/kd4kjdck/6/)**

Comment: Or `display: inline`: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kd4kjdck/5/). Result is the same.

Comment: sorry complete coding newbie:

`div.itemscope{
    display: inline-block;
}`

not working?

Comment: You need to set a class or id...itemscope is not a class or id . ex: div.yourclass{  display: inline-block; }, i edit my answer.